# One algorithm for drawing graph of implicit function

Tags: algorithms, graphing-functions

All! Does anybody know who is author of algorithm described [here](http://www.batesville.k12.in.us/physics/CalcNet/grapher/how_it_works.htm) and is the proposed solution correct?

Comment: Sounds right, but it would indeed be slow. You might want to look into Jeff Tupper's work as well.

Comment: I suspect this algorithm is too obvious and well-known to have any specific author. It's OK, but there are better ones; see for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131815/how-to-plot-implicit-equations and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marching_squares .

Comment: In order to get a truly reliable algorithm you need to use interval arithmetic with correct rounding. Here's a link to a paper by Tupper (as mentioned by J. M.): http://www.dgp.toronto.edu/people/mooncake/papers/SIGGRAPH2001_Tupper.pdf

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See these papers:

- K.G Suffern, [Quadtree algorithms for contouring functions of two variables](http://dx.doi.org/10.1093/comjnl/33.5.402), The Computer Journal 33 (5) (1990), pp. 402–407.
- Suffern KG, Fackerell ED. [Interval methods in computer    graphics](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0097-8493%2891%2990002-Y), *Computers and Graphics*, 15 (1991), 331–340.
- "Going the Distance" in *Andrew Glassner's Notebook*, originally in *IEEE Computer Graphics & Applications*, vol. 17, no. 1, January 1997, pp. 78-84 [doi](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=576861).