# What is the most efficient way to tile a regular shape inside an irregular shape?

Tags: geometry, area

Suppose you have a roughly circular irregular 2D shape, and want to tile as many regular squares (or rectangles) inside this shape as possible.

What would be the most efficient way to go about this?

Some constraints include:

- The regular shapes can extend outside the irregular shape, though would prefer not to.
- The regular shapes cannot overlap.
- You do not need to use 100% of the irregular shape's area, though less wasted space is preferred.
- It is preferable to maintain whole regular shapes inside the irregular shape resulting in some non-tiled space rather than having lots of regular shapes hanging outside the irregular shape.

Any reading materials would be appreciated too!

Answer (score 0):

If the squares or rectangles are all the same size and orientation, then the problem is the same as rasterizing the input shape. The solution depends on how the shape is given. Abstractly, it relies on a predicate that can decide whether a square is inside or outside the shape.

If the squares or rectangles can have different sizes but same aspect and orientation, then a good solution is to compute a quadtree approximation for the shape. If needed, neighbor squares of the same type can be merged into larger squares. Again, the predicate above is key. For shapes given implicitly, interval methods are simple to implement; see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/32528/one-algorithm-for-drawing-graph-of-implicit-function) for instance.

[image]

(image found [here](http://www.questinygroup.com/tag/quad-tree/))